# How to get a reply from a subdirectory back into the same subdirectory

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, rules

I am working with MS Outlook 2016.
I am subscribed to a mailing list, and I have created a rule, moving every mail towards that mailing list to a specific directory.

I regularly receive e-mails, containing different recipients, including the mentioned mailing list, and after those mails have been moved to my specific directory, I reply to all recipients of such a mail.

In case one of the recipients has enabled his out-of-office, then I get this out-of-office reply in my inbox.
This is a correct behaviour of the rule: the out-of-office reply is only sent to me (no reply-all for an out-of-office, which is correct), the mailing list is not there anymore, so the rule does not see a reason for moving the mail to a specific directory.

I believe that the best approach of this situation is a "rule" saying:

```
When a mail is sent from a directory,
then any reply to this mail should be moved towards that directory.
```

Is it possible to create such a rule?
Or is there any MS Outlook configuration for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the answer is No. The out-of-office reply has nothing related to the mailing list within the reply itself even within the message internet header. So, there is no rule condition can be used to achieve the goal.

Comment: So there is no configuration in Outlook which says "When a mail is sent from a particular folder", any reply must be moved towards that folder" (Not only out-of-office, but all types of mails)? This looks like an interesting feature to me.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Outlook rule configurations do not cover folder related conditions.